# If Condition in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on a legacy system, and many of the database structures are horrendous (key / value pairs).

I have the following select statement:

```
(
    SELECT D.F_VALUE
        FROM T_WEB_QUOTES_DATA D
        WHERE
            D.F_QUOTE_ID = TO_CHAR(VR_RENTAL.QUOTEID)
        AND D.F_KEY = 'Secondary_Driver_Forename'
) AS "SECONDARY_DRIVER_FORENAME"
```

So as you can see it is looking for a record where the `F_Key` column has a value of `Secondary_Driver_Forename`. The problem is there is another `F_Key` that holds the same exact information and I need to check for both keys.

So what I want to do is:

If there are no records where F_Key = Secondary_Driver_Forename or of such a record exists, but the value is an empty string or null, then I would like to go and look for a record where the F_Key is `2ndary_Driver_FirstName` and if that does not exist (or is null), I would like to return a string saying `No Key`

How can I achieve this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking of something like this:

```
(
    SELECT (case when max(case when D.F_KEY in 'Secondary_Driver_Forename' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
                 then max(case when D.F_KEY in 'Secondary_Driver_Forename' then D.F_VALUE end)
                 else max(D.F_Value)
            end)
        FROM T_WEB_QUOTES_DATA D
        WHERE
            D.F_QUOTE_ID = TO_CHAR(VR_RENTAL.QUOTEID)
        AND D.F_KEY in ('Secondary_Driver_Forename', '2ndary_Driver_FirstName')
) AS "SECONDARY_DRIVER_FORENAME";
```

That is, do a conditional aggregation of the values.  If the primary value is present, then use it.  Otherwise, just choose the value that is there (either `NULL` or the value from the second key).